# CKEditor 4: outdent icon is disabled when none-text

Tags: ckeditor, indentation, disabled-control

In ckeditor, when textarea has notext, outdent icon is being disabled. I researched but can't find any solution (I Know that I couldn't look at right where :) ).

How can I do available this icon?

[image]

At ckeditor's web-site this icon is available. (http://ckeditor.com/addon/tweetabletext at the bottom of page-comment area)

Thanks..

Comment: I assume that it work only for heading and subheading.

Comment: At ckeditor's web-site this icon is available. ([link](http://ckeditor.com/addon/tweetabletext) at the bottom of page-comment area)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written on the [Indent plugin page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/indent), the indenting functionality is split into two parts: [indenting lists](http://ckeditor.com/addon/indentlist) and [indenting blocks](http://ckeditor.com/addon/indentblock), both handled by separate plugins.

The CKEditor package that you use apparently contains only the Indent and Indent List plugins, but does not contain the Indent Block plugin, so the buttons are disabled for text blocks. See the installation packages comparison [here](http://ckeditor.com/presets). Download another preset (Full) or use [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) to add the missing plugin to your package and create a custom build.

Comment: As an addendum to your answer for anyone else dealing with this issue, I had the same symptoms but it was related to using the AutomaticMode of the contentfilter. We had classes like ind1, ind2, etc. When the filter was turned on this broke everything. This was true if we had classes ind10, ind11 etc. Switching these to indA, indB, etc. fixed this issue for us.